# Why bootstrap button no linking to another page?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, href

I made this code. I need the two first buttons take me to other page but it is not working. I am usin *href*.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="menu-principal">
<h2>MENÚ PRINCIPAL</h2>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/enviarSMS.html">Enviar SMS</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/agregarNumero.html">Agregar número de celular</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">SALIR</button>
</div>
```

Comment: use <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/enviarSMS.html">Enviar SMS</a> instead. button doesn't have href.

Comment: Use <a href="your url">link test</a> instead of button tag. It will work.

Comment: instead of using button use anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

If you want link, use `a` tag, not `button`:

```
<a class="btn btn-link btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/enviarSMS.html">Enviar SMS</a>
```

Comment: add the missing tag letter.

Comment: And I think bootstrap is used - so btn class makes it look like button already.

Answer (score 0):

try `a` tag instead of `button` tag

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu-principal">
    <h2>MENÚ PRINCIPAL</h2>    
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/enviarSMS.html">Enviar SMS</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="/agregarNumero.html">Agregar número de celular</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">SALIR</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="menu-principal">
<h2>MENÚ PRINCIPAL</h2>

    <a href="/enviarSMS.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Enviar SMS</button></a>
    <a href="/agregarNumero.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Agregar número de celular</button> </a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">SALIR</button>
</div>
```

You have to use `<a>` tag. You can't add href to `<button>`

Answer (score 0):

**You need to update your code as below:-**

used **a** tag instead of **button**. And also checked the required refrences of bootstrap Scripts (JS and CSS).

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="menu-principal">
<h2>MENÚ PRINCIPAL</h2>

    <a href="/enviarSMS.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Enviar SMS</a><br>
    <a href="/agregarNumero.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Agregar número de celular</a><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">SALIR</button>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**and also use:-**

```
<div id="browse_app">
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-info" href="templates/home.html">Browse</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu-principal">
      <h2>MENÚ PRINCIPAL</h2>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
           <a href="/enviarSMS.html"> Enviar SMS</a>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
           <a href="/agregarNumero.html"> Agregar número de celular</a>   
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">SALIR</button>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML does not allow A elements inside BUTTON elements.

Comment: Sorry. It will be

    `<div class="container">
     <div class="menu-principal">

        <h2>MENÚ PRINCIPAL</h2>
        <a href="/enviarSMS.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> Enviar SMS</button></a>
        <a href="/agregarNumero.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> Agregar número de celular</button></a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">SALIR</button>
        </div>`

Comment: HTML does not allow BUTTON elements inside A elements either.

Comment: You mean it works in the limited number of browsers you tested it with … presumably without combining any of them with a screen reader or other AT … and it isn't allowed — the HTML spec is quite clear about that — you've just tested in environments with error recovery that happens to work in this case.